# Should I be concerned about fine black dust coming from the back of a PC’s rear exhaust fan?

Tags: display, cpu, performance

I have a Lenovo All-In-One and I have been using it for a couple of years now.

Recently I relocated it to a more confined room which has a window for ventilation and I have noticed that there is a fine black dust that settles on the desk and the objects behind the PC. It's a really fine [dust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpAJ.jpg) that stains paper, somewhat like graphite.

Is this something that I should be worried about? I haven't had this issue until now so I hope there is a definite explanation for this.

I would probably rule out any external/pollution causes as I don't live in a very polluted area. Also its the precipitation of a "fixed" type of dust, not the ordinary lint-and-dead skin dust.
I've added an image for better clarity.

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned. It is an external issue (not your home or computer issue. Close the window and see if you can get internal residence air circulation .

Comment: I myself would also consider what that might be doing to my lungs.. not just my power supply.

Comment: @John In that case the air circulation is very limited.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have considered that but I'm really not in the position to buy an air purifier,so I'll have to wait and see.

Comment: Do you live near a large airport or coal fired power plant?

Comment: @Moab Far from that.I live a good distance from the main street and I haven't seen this before.

Comment: If you're in doubt if it's the computer or not: how quickly does it show? If it's visible after, say, one day: could you move the computer to some other location for that same time frame?

Comment: @Arjan There is a visible collection of dust within 5 to 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

The window probably gives on to a very busy street
(or is a factory to be found just across the road?).

It's not a problem for the computer itself. It will just force you to clean up the
area frequently, as well as the computer air-ways. Open up the computer from time
to time and vacuum the dirt out, especially the fans.

Comment: I live a good distance from the streets,so I was wondering if there was an issue with the PC itself that was causing thuis peculiar dust precipitation.

Comment: Unlikely, as only a fire can cause ashes and most likely you would have known about it. The simplest way to be sure is to open up the computer, and if nothing then search for some other cause for this pollution. This reminds me of a time when I was living near a highway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a printer nearby? Printers that use powder toner rather than liquid ink can sometimes emit a small cloud or light dusting of powdered toner. I've had users with small laserjet printers at their desk claim that their printer is "smoking", and it appears as if a cloud of smoke emerges from the printer when they would print but it's actually a "plume" or smallish cloud of airborne toner

Comment: Nope.No printers or any other external devices nearby.

Answer (score -1):

I am also experiencing same issues. I would wipe it off and next day it will come back. I am also using All in One PC, Dell brand. My desk is in confined room, no window, no wind, no aircon, sometime fan and very clean! Have you or anyone find out why/the cause/solution? Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1110962)